# Find all the child at N'th level in self referencing schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

suppose i have a self referencing schema like

```
Customer = { 
     email : {type : String, unique : true}
     referral : {type: String, ref: 'Customer', default: null}
}
```

Is it possible to find the `n'th` level children given the customer _id in **single query**..?

Comment: Yes its possible. Have a look at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/).

Comment: Awesome. But Unfortunately i am using version 3.0 which dont support $graphLookup